# Jfreechart: Display weeks on x axis for value of days

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart, week-number, days

I am using JFreeChart to display a value for each day of a month.
Now I want to have my x-axis display the weeks in a month instead of the days.
At the moment the values for my graph are double on the y-axis and int on the x axis.

`Timestamp ts = a.getTimestamp();
Double val = a.getVal();
series1.add(ts.getDate(), val);`

I am using 
`plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(0, 31);`
to set the range for the days to one month and 
`xax.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(7));`
for the x-axis to display the ticks at the right position. Instead of displaying the days (0, 7, 14, 21, 28) i want them to be weeks (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

Is that even possible, and how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) for your time axis, like [`ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.2168) does. Then you can use `setDateFormatOverride()`, like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264230/261156), and the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for "week in month."

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(…);
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("W"));
```