# Combining XYPlot and TimeSeries elements in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am interested in making a sort of hybrid between an XY Chart and Time Series in JFreeChart, where the x-axis is some SimpleDateFormat element (say, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"), with a respective start and end in the domain that is in this format, and the y-axis are levels, say LOW, MEDIUM, and HIGH. For each specific date/time, I would like to plot one of these three levels. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to combine several elements to get the desired effect:

- Start with [`ChartFactory.createXYBarChart()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createXYBarChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation-boolean-boolean-boolean-), as shown below and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612723/230513).
- Use a [`DateAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) for the domain axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42612723/230513).
- Use `setDateFormatOverride()` on the domain axis to apply your `SimpleDateFormat`.
- Use a [`SymbolAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SymbolAxis.html) for the range axis to replace integer values with your symbols, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890646/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839170/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I got most of it working, I just need to figure out how I can add a Date attribute instead of the doubles that are required for adding plots (e.g., add(double, Date) instead of add(double, double)). Could you help me out with that?

Comment: `DateAxis` interprets your values as milliseconds since the epoch; the example uses `TimeSeries` to make it a little more transparent, but `double` works, too, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513).

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped!