# JFreeChart duplicate dates with expand browser window

Tags: duplicates, window, jfreechart, axis, expand

I´m using JFreeChart generating this correct graph:

[image: Correct graph:]

But, when I expand the browser window, the graph duplicate the months (X axis) like this:

[image: Incorrect graph:]

Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you illustrate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*JFreeChart: X Axis contains time stamps*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264230/230513).